# Why is my brush width changing for no apparent reason?

Tags: gimp, brush

My paintbrush tool on Gimp has recently started to act up to the point where it’s frustrating to use. I have reinstalled the program but it did not resolve the problem. I checked to see if it was a sensitivity issue with my tablet but no dice; it will shrink and grow my strokes with both my mouse and my computer’s touch screen, and I can’t figure out what I did.

[image]

The picture I’ve provided are my attempts to figure out what I’ve done. they are with both my laptop’s touch screen and my touch pad. It is doing this with all of my  brushes including my eraser.

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - ***Please*** look through **[tour]** to get a sense of what our community is about; *then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a **good** query here, *and* how best to frame it. Note that questions which largely boil down to tech support - especially hardware specific - are generally avoided here; yours seems perilously close to that as currently framed. Please read [ask] and see if you can figure out how to revise your question to better fit the guidelines. Thanks! That said - it does sound and look like a stylus sensitivity issue to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this happens because you are using *Brush Dynamics* (which unfortunately are off-screen in the *Tool options* dialog in your screenshot, but it looks like the *Speed size opacity* one). Make sure your *Brush Dynamics* are set to *Dynamics off* (or whatever you explicitly selected):

[image]